# How to get CidrBlock value from VPC object input to cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, vpc, aws-security-group

I have a cloudformation template. I take as input a VPC. I want to get the CidrBlock value from the VPC input. How can I do this?

I can take `AWS::EC2::VPC::Id` as an input, but this appears to simply be a reference to the physical ID. I tried to take `AWS::EC2::VPC` as input, but it appears this type is not recognized by cloud formation.

Here is my code:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"

Parameters:
  pVpc:
    Description: "The VPC"
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id

Resources:
  rSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref pVpc
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: -1
          CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"
          # !GetAtt pVpc.CidrBlock    # <-- How can I do this?
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that unless you deploy `Lambda backed custom resource` that will take your `VPC Id` as input and return associated `CIDR block`.

Other option is to export CIDR block from the CFT that created the VPC and reference that exported variable in your current CFT.